# How can I determine programmatically whether the user has set their Mac to "set date and time automatically"?

Tags: macos, cocoa, datetime, plist

My software relies on being in sync with external servers. I'd like to programmatically check whether the user's computer (Mac OS X 10.5+) sets the date and time automatically, as per the checkbox in the Date & Time system preferences panel.

If this setting is not checked, my software will alert the user of potential problems with my software as a consequence.

I'd imagine there is either a way to do this using a Cocoa library, or a plist file my software can open and read.

Answer (score 1):

I just tested. If the checkbox is checked, `ntpd` runs. Otherwise it doesn't run. So just check to see if `ntpd` is running.

You could check this directly by shelling out to `ps -ef` and checking for a `/usr/sbin/ntpd` process in the output or you could use any number of other methods to detect its presence:

- Run `ntpq -c lpeers` and check for successful return status
- Check with `netstat -an` or equivalent to see if something is listening on UDP port 123.
- Send a UDP packet yourself to 127.0.0.1 port 123 and see if that's successful.